# Не понимаю по какому алгоритму идет заполнение

Tags: c++, visual-c++

[image: Дико туплю с задачей,не понимаю, как заполняется матрица!!]

Не совсем понимаю, по какому алгоритму идет заполнение. Если мы берем, допустим, в первом столбце максимальный от M до 1, то почему у нас идет 1, 2, 3...
И тому подобное
Очень надеюсь на то, что кто-то сможет подсказать или объяснить

Comment: по алгоритму `max(i,j)`

Comment: Честно говоря, понятнее не стало

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте код в тело вопроса в виде текста, а не изображения. Для этого используйте ссылку «[edit]», расположенную под метками вопроса.

Comment: Максимальное из номера строки и столбца

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer:* псевдо-код.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    A[i,j] = max(j+1,i+1);
```

Comment: @Kazer На здоровье. Успехов в программировании!