# Для чего нужно (char *) при взятии адреса &mass_size?

Tags: c++, fstream

Нужно записать в бинарный файл число типа int, хранящееся в переменной mass_size

```
fin.write((char *)&mass_size, sizeof(int))
```

Для чего нужно (char *) при взятии адреса &mass_size?

Comment: Кстати, Вы тут не забыли принять ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628921 ?

Comment: Вопрос не имеет никакого смысла без указания того, что такое `fin`. Почему эта информация отсутствует в вопросе?

Answer (score 4):

Используемый вами метод `write`, очевидно, принимает параметр типа `char *` или что-то в этом роде. Так как неявные преобразования указателей в/из типа `char *` в С++ не поддерживаются, их приходится прописывать явно. `(char *)` - это и есть явное преобразование указателя `&mass_size` к типу `char *`. Кто-то, возможно, заметит, что в С++ коде разумнее было бы выразить его как `reinterpret_cast<char *>(&mass_size)`.

Например, метод `write` стандартного класса `std::ostream` принимает именно `const char *`. Почему именно `const char *`, а не `const void *`? Вероятнее всего для того, чтобы подчеркнуть тот факт, что метод `write` - это НЕ метод для записи в поток именно *бинарных* данных, а метод для *посимвольной* записи именно *символьной последовательности* явно указанной длины. Если поток открыт в текстовом режиме, символы этой последовательности будут потенциально подвергнуты соответствующим преобразованиям, что делает такую запись уже совсем не "бинарной". "Бинарность" записи определяется именно свойствами самого потока, а не [только] выбранным для записи методом.